# Provide a pointer to member function to be invoked by the target class without functional

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member, avr-gcc

I'm reading a lot of questions (and answers) about function pointers, functors and callbacks but I still have a confusion about which is the right tool for me.

Some of them cannot apply to my scenario because it seems my compiler avr-gcc v5.4.0 does not have C++ standard library (i.e. `std::function` is not available).

This is my base class:

```
class Debouncer
{
public:
    typedef uint8_t (Debouncer::*debouncer_raw_t) (void);

    Debouncer() {}
    void setRawFunction(Debouncer::debouncer_raw_t callback) { _raw = callback; }

private:
    debouncer_raw_t _raw;
    void anotherFunction()
    {
        uint8_t value = _raw();
        // do something
    }
}
```

In my other classes I have:

```
class Inputs
{
public:
    Inputs()
    {
        _deb.setRawFunction(myRaw);
    }

private:
    Debouncer _deb;
    uint8_t myRaw()
    {
        return something;
    }
}
```

Of course this won't compile because `myRaw` is not static.
Anyway, I'm going to try to avoid this because it would break the existing code.

If I'm not wrong, a lot of questions seem to ask the other way around.
Instead I just want to pass the pointer of my member function to my `Debouncer` class, so it can call `_raw()` when it needs to.

[Here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr) I found this advise to avoid `std::` library:

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object, ptrToMember)  ((object).*(ptrToMember))

void userCode(Fred& fred, FredMemFn p)  // Use a typedef for pointer-to-member types
{
  int ans = CALL_MEMBER_FN(fred,p)('x', 3.14);
  // Would normally be: int ans = (fred.*p)('x', 3.14);
  // ...
}
```

But it seems the other way around. Here the class `Fred` is my `Debouncer`.
I don't want to call the `Debouncer` member, but member of the *caller* class (i.e. `Input::myRaw()`).

Would you please help me to understand which is the right tool to achieve such a simple task?

Comment: Your compiler must come with standard library, but [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is a C++11 feature. You can try to compile with `-std=c++11` to see if you compiler actually supports it. `std::function` is not very fast, but unless you desperately need those few processor cycles it should be good enough (and easy to understand!)

Comment: I'm already compiling with `-std=c++11` but here it seems the standard library is not available: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/462260. And issuing `grep -nrw . -e std::function` inside the compiler directory returns nothing.

Comment: Overloading the function call operator (`operator()`) could have been done.  That doesn't require C++11.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I apologize but I cannot see how overloading the call operator should solve my problem.

Comment: @Mark - if you require `Inputs` to have overloaded `operator()`, then the problem is much easier - you only need to keep `Inputs` object and nothing else. Same with most other names - if you know a type provides `foo()`, you can call it directly, no function pointers. The final option would be templates - you still need to save the object and pointer-to-member-function, but at least you don't have to specify each type as a separate overload.

Comment: @Mark -- Overloading the call operator is much more powerful and is much more than simply another way to call a function.  The object where the call operator is overloaded has state, member variables that could be set as the parameters, all sorts of things that mere function pointers do not have the ability of having.  And all of this is available in C++ 98.

Comment: The type `uint8_t (Debouncer::*) ()` is entirely unrelated to `uint8_t (Input::*) ()`. In order to call a pointer-to-member, you need both a pointer and an instance of the corresponding type.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, perhaps I explained it wrong. `Debouncer` instances will be created in several other classes (in this example `Inputs`, then say `Foo1`, `Foo2`, etc... they are very different each other). But each one of these "parent" classes has a `myRaw` function, specific for it. Hence, I need to pass this specific `myRaw` function in each instance of `Debouncer`.

Comment: From the way this question is written, I'm not convinced that it's clear that a non-`static` member function can not be called without also having a pointer (or equivalent) to an instance of that class.  The member function requires an implicit "this" parameter to be passed to it.

Comment: @DrewDormann, I'm aware I have to pass `this` as implicit parameter. But I cannot understand the proper syntax. I mean, when I make the call to `setRawFunction` the context is well defined! `this` exists and points to the correct "parent" class.

Comment: @Mark in your _real code_, which seems to involve a class hierarchy, is the function `virtual`?  Does the function always have the same name?  Virtual functions are another common way to solve this problem.

Comment: Nope, right now the functions are not virtual and the code looks like the example (I just cut out the non-relevant functions and variables). But I can easily make all the `myRaw` functions with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a member function `virtual` is a relatively low-overhead way to have a single pointer (to an object) refer to both the object's data and the correct member function.

```
class InputsBase
{
    // All classes that implement myRaw() should inherit from this class
public:
    virtual uint8_t myRaw() = 0;
};

class Inputs : public InputsBase
{
public:
    Inputs()
    {
        _deb.setRawFunction(this);
    }

private:
    Debouncer _deb;
    virtual uint8_t myRaw()
    {
        return something;
    }
}
```

Your Debouncer can then simply store a pointer to the object in question.

```
class Debouncer
{
public:
    typedef InputsBase* debouncer_raw_t;

    Debouncer() {}
    void setRawFunction(debouncer_raw_t callback) { _raw = callback; }

private:
    debouncer_raw_t _raw;
    void anotherFunction()
    {
        uint8_t value = _raw->myRaw();
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach! Only two things I had to change: `typedef debouncer_raw_t InputsBase*;` -> `typedef InputsBase* debouncer_raw_t;` and I had to add `public:` before the virtual function in `InputsBase`.

Comment: @Mark since C++11 introduced `using`, my `typedef` syntax has clearly fallen apart.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know (or require) each of the classes using `Debouncer` have a public `myRaw()` function (or better `operator()`, or actually anything else), the problem is simpler:

```
template <typename T>
class Debouncer
{
public:
    Debouncer (T* t): _t(t) {}
    void anotherFunction()
    {
        uint8_t value = _t->myRaw();
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(value);
    }
    
private:
    T* _t;
};

class Inputs
{
public:
    Inputs() : _deb(this)
    {
        // beware, if Debouncer uses its parameter in constructor (like call a method), 
        // you cannot use initializer list
    }
    
    uint8_t myRaw()
    {
        return 13;
    }
    
    void foo()
    {
        _deb.anotherFunction();
    }

private:
    Debouncer<Inputs> _deb;
};

int main()
{
    Inputs i;
    i.foo();
}
```

This would be preferred solution in C++. See for example standard library [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) - any function taking a predicate or some other callable expects to call it with `operator()` rathen than having to deal with pointers-to-member-function.

If you don't know what function should be called and you really cannot impose any requirement on the classes, you need to store both a pointer (or reference) to the class and a pointer to the member function. Note that you cannot connect pointers to member functions of different classes, so we need templates once again:

```
template <typename T, typename Func>
class Debouncer
{
public:
    Debouncer (T* t, Func f): _t(t), _f(f) {}
    void anotherFunction()
    {
        uint8_t value = (_t->*_f)(); //I get it now why isocpp asks to use macro here, the syntax is horrible
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(value);
    }
    
private:
    T* _t;
    Func _f;
};

class Inputs
{
public:
    Inputs() : _deb(this, &Inputs::myRaw)
    {
        // beware, if Debouncer uses its parameter in constructor (like call a method), 
        // you cannot use initializer list
    }
    
    uint8_t myRaw()
    {
        return 13;
    }
    
    void foo()
    {
        _deb.anotherFunction();
    }

private:
    Debouncer<Inputs, decltype(&Inputs::myRaw)> _deb; //decltype is C++11, you could also declare type like you did in your question

};

int main()
{
    Inputs i;
    i.foo();
}
```